# 'doesn't exits in current context' error - super simple

Tags: c#

I opened a program I had made yesterday which ran just fine yesterday but today in Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows, the 'Console' part of all of the 'Console.WriteLine("");' are underlined in red, giving the error 'doesnt exist in current context' - Ive looked for several solutions but I cant find any - I've just started out and its frustrating not being able to test my programs, the code below is a super simple version that gives the same error. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Start
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is an Error :S");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that really your code? I would expect that error if you class was named System or something like that...

Comment: I have known the error highlighting to get confused at times. Does it actually refuse to compile? You may find that it actually works and its just the display that is incorrect.

Comment: Have you tried `using System.Object;` or `using System.Console;`?

Comment: Is it "Express for Windows" or "Express for Windows Desktop"? I'm not sure that the former supports any project types where `System.Console` is supported.

Comment: I have tried System.Console... and the same error but on the 'System.Console' part...

Comment: and its Express for Windows :D

Comment: Is it Windows forms? When you first created the project, what did you choose?

Comment: it was Visual C# -> Blank App (Universal Apps)

Comment: I just tested it in a blank windows app and it still gives the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to create a Windows 8 app. `Console` is unavailable in this type of app as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230302%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> Types and members that are not applicable to developing Windows Store
>   apps (such as console and ASP.NET types).

Comment: That makes sense but he said he tried yesterday and it was working

Comment: Ah sorry, you're right, I missed that. It's strange it would work in a Windows 8 app in the first place :/

Comment: thats it!! :D <3 i was on my laptop yesterday (windows 7) thankyou

Comment: @oscholten - do you realise that saying "it worked yesterday" usually implies, without further qualification, "on this machine, using this version of Visual Studio", rather than "on a completely different machine using a different version of Visual Studio" - how were we meant to guess at that when you just said "it worked yesterday"?

Answer (score 0):

There is no namespace.  Wrap the existing class in a namespace.